# SQL Server 2008 Passing Multi-value Parameters or Parameter Array to a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I have two tables tbl_Properties and tbl_Locations

tbl_Properties has list of properties (including FK Location_Id)
tbl_Location has a list of locations

I am using following stored procedure to search properties in a location:

```
spPropGetSearch

(
@Location_Id int
)

AS

SELECT
P.Prop_Id,
P.Prop_Title,
P.Prop_Bedrooms,
P.Prop_Price,
L.Location_Title

FROM 
tbl_Properties P
INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id

WHERE
(P.Location_Id = @Location_Id OR @Location_Id = '0')
ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC
```

I pass location_id (such as '1002') and it works just fine and returns properties located within that location / area.
Now, I want to pass multiple location_Ids such as '1002', '1005', '1010' to search properties located in all of those areas.

How would I do that? 
I will appreciate a detailed reply as I am not a database expert.

**I found the following example and it's working fine. Please can you look into and check if there's any vulnerability**

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Employeelist
@Cities NVARCHAR(30)
AS
DECLARE @CitiesXML AS XML
SET @CitiesXML = cast(('<a>'+replace(@Cities,',' ,'</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML)

SELECT
BusinessEntityID
, FirstName
, JobTitle
, City
FROM HumanResources.vEmployee
WHERE City IN
(
SELECT
A.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
FROM @CitiesXML.nodes('A') AS FN(A)
)
ORDER BY BusinessEntityID
GO

--Execute the stored procedure using multiple values
--through one parameter in this stored procedure
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
EXEC usp_Employeelist
'Cambridge,Newport Hills,Berlin,Bordeaux'
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The first step is to create your type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfInt AS TABLE (Value INT);
```

I tend to use generic names for these to allow for reuse without any confustion as to names (e.g. if you named it `LocationIDs` it would then become confusing to store a list of properties in the type).

Then you can reference this type in your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spPropGetSearch @LocationIDs dbo.ListOfInt READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  P.Prop_Id,
            P.Prop_Title,
            P.Prop_Bedrooms,
            P.Prop_Price,
            L.Location_Title
    FROM    tbl_Properties P
            INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L 
                ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id

    WHERE   P.Location_Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LocationIDs)
    OR      @Location_Id = 0
    ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC;
END
```

You can then call this using something like:

```
DECLARE @LocationIDs dbo.ListOfInt;
INSERT @LocationIDs (Value)
VALUES (1002), (1005), (1010);
EXECUTE dbo.spPropGetSearch @LocationIDs;
```

**EDIT**

Found the error, it was here:

```
OR      @Location_Id = 0
```

Which leads me on to a new point, it looks like you want to have an option to return everything if `0` is passed. I would do this using `IF/ELSE`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spPropGetSearch @LocationIDs dbo.ListOfInt READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LocationIDs)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  P.Prop_Id,
                P.Prop_Title,
                P.Prop_Bedrooms,
                P.Prop_Price,
                L.Location_Title
        FROM    tbl_Properties P
                INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L 
                    ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id
        WHERE   P.Location_Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LocationIDs)
        ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  P.Prop_Id,
                P.Prop_Title,
                P.Prop_Bedrooms,
                P.Prop_Price,
                L.Location_Title
        FROM    tbl_Properties P
                INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L 
                    ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id
        ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC;
    END
END
GO
```

So if the table valued parameter passed is empty, it will return all records, if it contains records it will only contain the location_ids supplied. Putting `OR` in queries like this makes it almost impossible for SQL Server to use an appropriate index.

---

**ADDENDUM**

---

To answer the comment

> instead of using: IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LocationIDs) how can we use OR condition in WHERE clause

My answer would be don't I suggested using `IF/ELSE` for a reason, not to over complicate things, but to improve performance. I had hoped to deter you from this approach when I said **"Putting OR in queries like this makes it almost impossible for SQL Server to use an appropriate index."**.

You could rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT  P.Prop_Id,
        P.Prop_Title,
        P.Prop_Bedrooms,
        P.Prop_Price,
        L.Location_Title
FROM    tbl_Properties P
        INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L 
            ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id
WHERE   P.Location_Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LocationIDs)
OR      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LocationIDs)
ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC;
```

The problem with this approach is, you really have two options in the same query, and these options are likely to need two different exection plans. If you have an index on `p.Location_ID`, and you have records in `@LocationIDs`, then the best query plan is to use an index seek on `tbl_Properties.Location_ID`. If `@LocationIDs` is empty, then the index seek is pointless and the best plan is a clustered index scan (table scan) on `tbl_Properties`. Since SQL Server uses cached plans, it can only cache on or the other, which means that if it stores the index seek option, every time you pass an empty table you have a sub-optimal plan, or alternatively, if it caches the table scan plan, every time you pass values for location ID you are not taking advantage of the index that is there.

One workaround is `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`:

```
SELECT  P.Prop_Id,
        P.Prop_Title,
        P.Prop_Bedrooms,
        P.Prop_Price,
        L.Location_Title
FROM    tbl_Properties P
        INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L 
            ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id
WHERE   P.Location_Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LocationIDs)
OR      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LocationIDs)
ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

This forces the query to be recompiled for ever execution to ensure you have the optimal plan for the current execution. But since you only really have two options, this is a lot of unnessecary recompilation. So the best option is to have two queries, each with it's own cached execution plan, and using the `IF/ELSE` flow operator to flow to the appropriate query based on what has been passed as `@LocationIDs`.

Comment: Hi, When I am creating SP following error coming: Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationIDs".

Comment: Hi, when I execute the SP error comes: Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with ListOfInt

Comment: data type of Location_Id is int

Comment: Not sure why you would be getting this error then. [It works on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40a8c/1). Have you copied the query exactly?

Comment: how would I call SP from ASP.NET?

Comment: It would depend on the context. There are a number of examples on the article linked in the answer (towards the bottom of the page). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi GarethD, just posted an example above, please can you check, if there's any vulnerability i.e. injection.

Comment: You are trying to ram a square peg into a round hole, but you have the round peg in your other hand, I don't understand why you wouldn't use table valued parameters for this. They are designed for exactly this purpose, passing multiple values in a parameter. The act of splitting a string is very easy in most application layers with some kind of `string.Split()` method. It is not so easy in SQL. TVPs will also perform better than any other method, as demonstrated in [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)

Comment: If you insist on doing it in SQL then I suggest you read [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), and also [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up). The method you have proposed is not safe against malformed strings, you cannot use XML characters in the string you want to split.

Comment: GarethD - I value your comments and looking into what you suggested, thanks again.

Comment: instead of using:  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LocationIDs) how can we use OR condition in WHERE clause, thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain why you should not use `OR`.

Comment: hmmm, trying to understand your points, the problem is I am using 6 different parameters (locations, tenure, status, types etc.) within where clause in my query, I can use 'IF/ELSE' but then I will have to   repeat 'SELECT' statements a lot of time, if I use 'OR' then I don't need to repeat SELECT statements. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I was not aware it was 6 different options, for 6 different options then you can probably get away with using `OR`, but you should use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as described above. [This article on the matter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isn-t-the-best-solution-the-all-in-one-search-query.aspx) is probably worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

```
     spPropGetSearch

        (
        @Location_Id varchar(500)
        )

        AS



DECLARE @strQuery varchar(MAX)
SET @strQuery='

        SELECT
        P.Prop_Id,
        P.Prop_Title,
        P.Prop_Bedrooms,
        P.Prop_Price,
        L.Location_Title

        FROM 
        tbl_Properties P
        INNER JOIN tbl_Locations L ON L.Location_Id = P.Location_Id

        WHERE
     P.Location_Id in ('+ @Location_Id+') OR @Location_Id = ''0''
        ORDER BY P.Prop_DateAdded DESC'

EXEC (@strQuery)
```

pass parameter in stored Procedure like as

```
EXEC spPropGetSearch '1002,1005,1010'
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1002,1005,1010' to data type int.

Comment: Hi Sunil Naudiyal, same problem: Must declare the scalar variable "@Location_Id".

Comment: This is not a good approach. The downfall of this is that it cannot used cached plans, so in most cases the query will have to be compiled with each execution. There is also scope for malformed SQL, e.g. `EXECUTE dbo.spPropGetSearch 'Error';`, which will compile, but will cause an invalid column name error. Or worse, malicious SQL could be passed, e.g. `EXECUTE dbo.spPropGetSearch '1); DROP TABLE tbl_Properties; --'` which will return data, but also drop a table (if the user has sufficient permissions).

Comment: Actually i was forgated to use single '' with OR @Location_Id = ''0'' now use.

Comment: I agree with GarethD, can't use this, injection attack possible,

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic qry.

```
create procedure  dropsp
@no varchar(100)
as
    begin 
        declare @nsql  nvarchar(1000)

        Set @nsql   = ' SELECT  *
                        FROM    db.dbo.tmptable
                        WHERE no in  (' + @no +')'

        exec  sp_executesql @nsql 
    end 
go
exec dropsp  'aaaaaaaa,bbbb'
```

Comment: This is not a good approach, even the example you have posted will cause an error (something like `invalid column name 'aaaaaaaa'`). It is also unlikely to be able to use cached execution plans because the query will need to be compiled for each different set of values passed, it is also vulnerable to malicious SQL (SQL Injection).